# Systemd x.timer refusing to start

Tags: 16.04, systemd

I'm attemping to do this: https://www.shivering-isles.com/lets-encrypt-renew-all-your-certs-using-systemd/

When I run my timer:

```
sudo systemctl start letsencrypt.timer
```

I get the error:

```
Job for letsencrypt.timerfailed. See "systemctl status letsencrypt.timer" and "journlctl -xe" for details.
```

`sudo journalctl -u letsencrypt.timer`:

```
-- Logs begin at Sat 2017-02-25 05:28:36 UTC, end at Fri 2017-03-03 15:18:23 
Mar 03 14:54:17 instanty-dev systemd[1]: letsencrypt.timer: Refusing to start
Mar 03 14:54:17 instanty-dev systemd[1]: Failed to start letsencrypt timer.
```

`letsencrypt.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Renews letsencrypt certificates  
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot  
WorkingDirectory=/opt/letsencrypt/  
ExecStart=/opt/letsencrypt/letsencrypt-auto renew
```

`letsencrypt.timer`:

```
[Unit]
Description=letsencrypt timer

[Timer]
OnCalendar=daily  
Persistent=true  
Unit=letsencrypt.service

[Install]
WantedBy=basic.target
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From reviewing the `systemd` source code, the only reason that a timer would emit "refusing to start" is if there was a problem with the service unit it needed to activate. Confirm that both your `.timer` and `.service` files are valid:

```
systemd-analyze verify /etc/systemd/system/letsencrypt.service
systemd-analyze verify /etc/systemd/system/letsencrypt.timer
```

Also confirm that you can start the letsencrypt service manually:

```
systemctl start letsencrypt
journalctl -u letsencrypt
```